# Not Updating values when their is a rendering

Tags: apex, visualforce, dml

I have a Vf page with rendering say

```
 <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!payment.paytype__c==true}">
     //My code goes here
  </apex:outputpanel>
```

In my class

```
public list<paypolicy__c> payment{get;set;}
    //constructor
    payid = apexpages().currentpage.getparameters().get('id');
    payment = [select paytype__c from paypolicy__c where id=:payid];
   //save method

    if(payid != null){
        //some code
       update payment;
    }
```

if (payment.paytype__c==true) this condition becomes true then Update is not working....Help!!!!

Comment: Please post your complete code.

Comment: Are you using rerender on that outputpanel?

Comment: yes using it....

Comment: I don't see an id on the output panel, you sure you have reRender="Output_Panel_Id" from the invocation which is causing the value to change? I would also try reRendering the pageBlock.

Comment: `<apex:pageblocksectionItem ><Apex:outputLabel value="Allow for Payments"/> <apex:outputpanel><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!payment.paytype__c}"> <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="SelectSection"/> </apex:inputcheckbox>
             </apex:outputpanel>     </apex:pageblocksectionItem>  </apex:pageblocksection>
<apex:outputpanel id="SelectSection"><apex:outputpanel rendered="{!payment.paytype__c==true}">
 //code here </apex:outputpanel>`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because you are using the onclick event - this happens as soon as the user clicks into that element and will fire before the checkbox state is updated.

If you change this to the onchange event, that will fire after the checkbox value has been updated.  Note that in some versions of IE the onchange doesn't fire until the element loses focus.

Comment: here my problem is it is rendering correctly...But when I go for update it is not updating

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the code that you have posted.